# How to add path to javascript file (not twig file)?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have app.js file and in it bunch of javascript code. Among other thing I want be ablt to add path.

```
var ul = " {{ path('chat_get_fnln', {'email':'%s'}) | url_decode | format('"+jid+"') | raw }}";
```

I need this in app.js not some twig file.

1) Is it such a thing even possible?
2) If yes please point me right direction.

I need this in .js file not in .twig.html!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use hidden elements in your html, rendered by twig, and load them using js. Anyway as Amine posted use FosJsRoutingBundle, is the best way to generate paths for js.

Comment: this is how I did it. Thanks.

Comment: Other way could be to use Ajax to get any params you need. It would be more reusable and clean because you don't mix data and structure with this aproach

Answer (score 2):

You can also use global JS variable in twig template

```
<script>
    if (typeof app == 'undefined'){
    app = [];
}
app['your_url'] = '{{ path('your_route') }}';
app['other_value'] = 'value';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a js file using a js.twig file. Or you can use [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown)

after you can do:

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });
```

Comment: This is not really a option. So no.